# C# UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

Unfortunately, the UserControl is not displayed in my ToolBox.
Since I have worked but with Windows Form, I have back remembers that you can create this UserControl also by code. And also tested in Windows Form where it has worked.

```
public partial class Einstellungcs : UserControl
{
    public Einstellungcs()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Einstellungcs settings = new Einstellungcs();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
            ......
}
```

---

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    panel.ContentMenu(settings );
}
```

These Code snippets Should sometimes illustrate what I mean.
Unfortunately, there is no more panel in WPF.
So how can I do this in WPF? I currently use Canvas, but this is not the right one. How would someone have the solution what I must use or how I have to make it?

I would like to change the content area by clicking the button
with a UserControl.Can someone explain to me how I can use the UserControl in WPF?

**EDIT**

[image]

If I click on the button "Vorschau" is to change the red area with a content. If I click on the button "Einstellung" a different content appears than before. It should change as the content always only in the red area, the rest should remain as it is.

Comment: You sould use a `Grid` and then use the `Grid.RowDefinitions` along with `Grid.ColumnDefinitions`(it's easier to see in the XAML Editor). It's simple to align content in there. You could then also add your `UserControl` to the red part and only switch `Visibility` when "Vorschau" is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In your **MainWindow** you need to put a **ContentControl** which will act as placeholder and after creating instance of the usercontrol set the content of the contentcontrol :

```
 <ContentControl x:Name="UserControlContainer"></ContentControl>
```

and then in code behind of Window inside the button click evebt, you can set the content property to use new user control following way:

```
Einstellungcs settings = new Einstellungcs();
this.UserControlContainer.Content = settings ;
```

Comment: First, thanks for the answer. I have now adopted this, but I click on the button happens nothing. No content is displayed. `private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Einstellungcs settings = new Einstellungcs();
            this.UserControlContainer.Content = settings;
            lbWhereIAm.Content = "Vorschau";
        }`

Comment: how your user control looks like? and put ContentControl in the Main Grid of the Window, how have you added that?

Comment: `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Vorschau
{
    public partial class Einstellungcs : UserControl
    {
        public Einstellungcs()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
    }
}` http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=205525-1487842565.png That's how it looks

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FD1K6NREY1AK this is the XAML-Code

Comment: put a textbox inside it and see if it appears, if that works then try assigning UserControl from code behind